# Как на php реализовать связь многие ко многим?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня 3 таблицы в базе:

1. Статьи (spisok) - 2 поля: `id`, `text`
2. Теги (tags) - 2 поля: `id`, `tag`
3. Cвязь (link) - 2 поля: `spisok_id`, `tags_id`

Хочу генерить универсальную таблицу вывода самой статьи и под ней список тегов для нее.
Как реализовать эту таблицу связей? Как искать и выводить несколько тегов, относящихся к странице?

Буду очень признателен любой помощи? Хотелось бы сам код php... я новичок и в псевдокоде не силен...

И какого типа должны быть данные во всех таблицах?

Comment: проблема в том что не можешь понять зачем тебе 3 таблицы и как вывести то что нужно?

Вся информация у тебя есть, нужно просто немножко пошевелиться.

Напиши что сделал чтобы работало? 

Так тебе код тут врядли кто-то напишет.

Comment: у тебя для этого есть таблица 

>3)Cвязь(link)-2 поля: spisok_id, tags_id

ну и ...

Comment: ну например spisok_id tags_id
                 1        2
                 2        1
                 1        3
ну вот я синтаксиса не знаю как это написать... я понимаю...что нужно например если статья с id=1 то проверять сколько раз встречается 1 и выводить соответствующий tag  с номером tags_id...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-й запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `spisok` WHERE `id`=ТВОЙИДСТАТЬИ
```

2-й запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `tags`, `link` WHERE `link`.`spisok_id`=ТВОЙИДСТАТЬИ AND `link`.`tags_id`=`tags`.`id`
```

Начните экспериментировать с phpmyadmin или каким-то другим инструментом, позволяющим упростить выполнение запросов к БД, например, HeidiSQL, по сравнению с командной строкой.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте лучше так сделаем :

Не будет третей таблицы со связями, а будем перечислять в третьем поле(**tags**) у статей теги, которым соответствуем эта статья, а пример этого в приложенном изображении.

Разбирать будет проще, меньше мороки с таблицами и нагрузки на базу.

[image]

Comment: Это интересно! Спасибо, Андрей Аршинов! А что правда будет меньше нагрузки на базу? Я правильно понимаю, что этот способ более рациональный????

Comment: Не намного, но рациональней способ.

Comment: и какого типа поле tags в таблице 'статьи'? я так понимаю они в phpmyadmine так и будут перечисляться? 1,2,3... через запятую?

Comment: можно написать varchar и выбрать длину 30-40 символом примерно, через запятую будут перечисляться идентификаторы тегов.

Comment: Вот по каким материалам я учился : http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ .
Сейчас код писать не могу, немного занят.